# Using BroadcastReceiver to check Battery Level but App crash?

Tags: android, broadcast, receiver

I am trying to get current battery level using broadcast receiver with intentfilter ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED having only one TextView in my xml and setting its text property to some string+integer variable that should hold value of BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL. But app crashes everytime it try to boot. 
Am i missing something?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvcl=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcl);

private BroadcastReceiver bcr=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int currentLevel=intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
        tvcl.setText("Current Battery Level "+ Integer.toString(currentLevel) + "%");
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    IntentFilter bcFilter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(bcr,bcFilter);
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: you are missing the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
TextView tvcl=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcl);
```

appears to be in the class definition and not in a method.
If so, then it will return null since the ContentView isn't set until OnCreate whereas this definition occurs at object creation time.

Comment: Thanx. Helped alot

Comment: @SilentCoder Why did you "unaccept" my answer? Any reason?

Comment: I accepted your answer. Maybe i don't have enough reputation to vote up.

Comment: @SilentCoder Weird. It seems to be re-accepted now. Thanks.